# How to Redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

How to Redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com using htaccess

Answer (score 4):

use a `.htaccess` file with following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In case of IIS make sure, that the host listens to all urls you want to use for your block (including www.example.com and example.com)

Then use the rewrite module of the IIS:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module

You can easily import rules from Apache mod_rewrite into ISS:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/470/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

By having a correct configured DNS.
Make sure you have following line:

```
@      IN A   your.server.ip.address
```

Which says anyone requesting yourdomain.bla will be sent to the server with the given IP. In your case, the IP-address would be the same as the CNAME configuration for "www".

Though, if you use a web hotel service they are too often not letting the customer make a default config. It might be then that you're not able to make the config needed.